# Why do recoilless rifle ammunition still have casings?

Tags: firearms

Recoiless guns have breeches that allow gas to escape out of the back of the gun. Therefore, theres no sealing action to be performed by the casing. Why is ammunition with perforated cases used, when a propellant bag (like in other types of artillery) affixed to the shell would be cheaper an lighter? Is it necessary to build up the pressure for combustion of the propellant?

Comment: Ease of loading?

Comment: [Caseless Ammunition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caseless_ammunition)